# How to append html string to a div in jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, asp.net, .net

I've a html string value from .net and stored in view data

in jquery i'm reading that like this

```
 var htmlTranTable = '@ViewData["tblView"]';    
                $('#divTransactions').append(htmlTranTable);
```

And this is the sample html string that i received from .net viewdata

```
var htmlTranTable = `<table class='table table-bordered row-border table-responsive' id='htmlTableTransactions'>
   <thead>
      <tr>
         <th class='text-nowrap'>Transaction No</th >
         <th class='text-nowrap'>Status</th >
      </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
      <tr>
         <td>510002500007484</td>
         <td>Completed With Migration Successful</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>510002500007475</td>
         <td>Completed With Migration Successful</td>
      </tr>     
   </tbody>
</table>`
```

when I try to append the value in a div like this

HTML/Div

```
<div class="table-responsive" id="divTransactions" style="overflow:hidden"></div>
```

JS

```
 $('#divTransactions').append(htmlTranTable); 
 // or
 document.getElementById("divTransactions").innerHTML += htmlTranTable;
```

when I run this I'm getting output like this image

[image]

as plain string inside the div .. please let me if you've any solution thanks

Comment: Javascript strings can't go across two lines - so you only have 1 js line and the rest is plain text.   Use `\`` or `"" + ""` etc

Comment: actully i added the html string just for sample only here in real time I'm getting the html string value from c#

Comment: It could be the way you are declaring the variable - you've tagged [asp.net] - maybe that is encoding it.  Try to recreate the issue in a snippet in the question.  **edit** or it's encoded in when you get it "from c#".

Comment: Seems to work fine for me (https://jsfiddle.net/vwe7186z/) - could you edit your question and use the snippet button to create a [mcve] demonstrating your issue - by the sounds of it, you probably have something html encoding your string before you append it

Comment: Your code, as provided, [works fine](https://jsfiddle.net/p4j0ask2/) (after changing `"` to `\``).  So must be that it's either stored encoded or when you retrieve it it is getting encoded.

Comment: Try debugging: look at the *rendered* source of your page and at the `htmlTranTable` variable directly.

Comment: By the looks of your edit, seems like it has been encoded in c# try - `@Html.Raw(ViewData["tblView"])` and see if that solves the issue

Answer (score 0):

try with one of these:

```
function appendData(id, datos) {
    var line = document.getElementById(id);
    var div = document.createElement("DIV");
    div.classList.add("col-6", "col-lg-12", "text-center", "px-1");
        div.innerHTML = datos;
        line.appendChild(div);
}
```

first create the div element inside your div, and then do the innerhtml like this. hopes it helps this example

Comment: but i've the div in my html code like this "<div class="table-responsive" id="divTransactions" style="overflow:hidden">
</div>"

Comment: you can add those classes in div.classList.add or the ID, but the gist of this is that if you want to do an innerHTML you have to create an HTML element first. If you want to create a table, you do document.createElement("table").

Answer (score -2):

You can use the below code

```
$('#divTransactions').html({Your HTML Code Or String});
Or if you get a string then use below code
$('#divTransactions').append($({Your HTML Code Or String}));
```

This is perfect for working with your code.